# MySQL won't start after setting external bind-address

Tags: mysql

I want to enable remote access to my MySQL server so I've set the bind-address option under [mysqld], which looks like:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
bind-address=**.**.**.66
port=3306
# skip-networking
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
```

When I comment bind-address, the server starts normally. However, when I comment it out it won't restart. The port is open and listens.

Can you please help me sort this out? Thanks

Comment: `**.**.**.66` isn't a valid IP address...

Comment: @womble, eh?  Isn't that just standard address obfuscation?

Comment: @Zoredache: We don't know, do we?  Perhaps that really is what he put in, and that's why it's not working.  The correct way to obfuscate addresses is to use the RFC5737 documentation networks.

Comment: Probably I should clarify this, in the actual my.cnf file I use the real IP address. I use * just to hide it here.

Comment: What was your configuration file? Was it "/etc/mysql/my.cnf"? Also do you solve the error?

Answer (score 8):

Why do you think you need to use `bind-address` to enable remote access?

Without the bind-address option try running the command `netstat -ntlp | grep 3306`.  If you see output like below, then mysql is listening on every IP associated with the computer.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23465/mysqld
```

You only really need the [bind-address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) if you want to listen on a specific IP.  If you want to listen for requests on all addresses you should leave that commented out or set it to `0.0.0.0`.  Some packaged versions of mysql come with startup/maintenance scripts that will attempt to access mysql on 127.0.0.1.  If you use the bind-address option then mysql will only be bound to that specific IP, and nothing else, possibly breaking any scripts that you currently have.

Comment: netstat: option -p requires an argument

Comment: It does not require an argument on the net-tools version of netstat on Linux.  What OS are you running on?  I know netstat has different syntax/options on Windows, and on BSD.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will help some folks:

It appears that if `bind-address` is declared in 2 places, the service fails to restart.

Perhaps you quickly scanned your `/etc/conf/my.cnf` file and did not see a 2nd appearance of `bind-address`. However, note that the file may contain a `!includedir` directive, and some of those included files can contain a 2nd `bind-address`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there isn't a stalled mysqld instance already started. Check

```
ps aux|grep mysqld
```

and kill all processes with

```
kill -9
```

then try to start mysqld again.
Pay attention to mysqld processes in "Sl" state.

Comment: and make sure the sky isn't falling and that the power grid is still alive.  Am I still breathing?